# What is wrong with my foreign key in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Whenever I try to run this script in mySQL I get an error that reads:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
CONSTRAINT ITEM_pk PRIMARY KEY(Item_Number),
CONSTRAINT ITEM_CATEGORY_fk FOREIG' at line 7

The code for the table it is referencing is on top and the code for the table with the failing foreign key constraint is below:

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY(
Category_Name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
ShippingPerPound DECIMAL(4,2),
OffersAllowed ENUM('y', 'n'),
CONSTRAINT CATEGORY_pk PRIMARY KEY(Category_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEM(
Item_Number int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
Item_Name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
Description varchar(255),
Model varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
Category_Name,
CONSTRAINT ITEM_pk PRIMARY KEY(Item_Number),
CONSTRAINT ITEM_CATEGORY_fk FOREIGN KEY (Category_Name) REFERENCES CATEGORY(Category_Name) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Category_Name declaration in your`ITEM` table is incomplete:

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM(
Item_Number int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
Item_Name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
Description varchar(255),
Model varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
Category_Name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ITEM_pk PRIMARY KEY(Item_Number),
CONSTRAINT ITEM_CATEGORY_fk FOREIGN KEY (Category_Name) REFERENCES CATEGORY(Category_Name) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```